# Dynamic data display on iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm working on a prototype iOS app and coding in Swift. The app has one screen with a TableViewController where clicking on one of the cells opens another screen (figure below).

[image: App Screens]

On this new screen, I'd like to show dynamic data, basically data related to the cell clicked. For that I have the object below (with which data may be loaded from a db, for instance).

```
import Foundation

import UIKit

class Obj: NSObject {
    var A: Float
    var B: Float
    var C: Float
    init(A: Float, B: Float, C: Float) {
        self.A = A
        self.B = B
        self.C = C
        super.init()
    }
}
```

I'm a newbie to Swift, and would appreciate if anyone could point me to a simple way in Swift to render this dynamic data on the screen shown. Many thanks.

Comment: This question is unfortunately far too broad for what would be considered a good answer. You could use UILabel, UITextView, UIWebView, Core Graphics, Core Animation...

Comment: Just create a new master-detailviewcontroller project and check the code which is already in the project. It should show you how you can access the tableview-data and display it dynamically.